# How to model statechart behavior inheritance using UML?

Tags: uml, statechart

I have the following very simple state machine:

[image: state machine]

I can't figure out how to model that, when in state AA, Event1 should be "handled" by both the child state AA and parent state A; while in the state AB, **only** AB should "handle" the event.

If you were looking at the print output, I want the following:

```
A
AA
-> Event1
AA:Event1
A:Event1
-> Event2
AB
-> Event1
AB:Event1
```

(I am notating an event being send to the state machine via an arrow ->)

How do I explicitly notate this type of behavior using UML?